# query a list and compare Id's to logged in userId

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a list model being passed into my view. But I want to separate the `Participant`'s inside the list depending on which `User` is logged in on the ViewBag.

**how I'm saving the logged in user to ViewBag from controller:**

```
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", dbUser.UserId);
        ViewBag.UserId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
```

**current view code:**

```
@model List<League>
    @{    
        if (Model != null && Model.Any())
        {
            foreach(League i in Model)
            {
                foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in i.allParticipants)
                {
                    <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                }  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p>the list is empty</p>
        }
    }
```

my code currently works but it is displaying all the `Participant`'s regardless of if they belong the to current logged in `User` or not.

**Solution I thought that might work:**

```
<p>Your kids:</p>
foreach(League i in Model)
{
    foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in i.allParticipants)
    {
        if(mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId == ViewBag.UserId )
        {
            <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
        }
    }
}
<p>All other kids:</p>
foreach(League i in Model)
{
    foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in i.allParticipants)
    {
        if(mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId != ViewBag.UserId )
        {
            <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
        }

    }
}
```

The error I get from trying this:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

it doesn't like the `if(mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId == ViewBag.UserId)` line.

---

**Models relations:**

- The `league` model and `ViewModel` (`Participant`) share a `MMLeagueParticipant` middle table for a many to many relationships (one `Participant` can play many `League`'s and many `League`'s can have many `Participant`'s)
- The `User` model has a one-to-many relationships with the `ViewModel`. (one Logged in `User` can have many `Participant`'s)

---

*My league model:*

```
int LeagueId { get; set; }
string sport { get; set; }
string gender { get; set; }
string ageRange { get; set; }

​List<MMLeagueParticipant> allParticipants  { get; set; }
```

---

*My ViewModel model:*

```
public List<Participant> allParticipants { get; set; }
public ViewModel.Participant participant { get; set; }

public class Participant
{
int ParticipantId { get; set; }
string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }
string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }
string ParticipantGender { get; set; }
System.DateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }

List<MMLeagueParticipant> allLeagues { get; set; }

int UserId { get; set; }
User Parent { get; set; }
}
```

---

*My MMLeagueParticipant middle table for the league model and ViewModel.Participant:*

```
int MMLeaugeParticipantId { get; set; }
int ParticipantId { get; set; }
int LeaugeId { get; set; }
leauge sport { get; set; }

ViewModel.Participant child { get; set; }
```

---

*My User model:*

```
int UserId { get; set; }
string FirstName { get; set; }
string LastName { get; set; }
string Email { get; set; }
string Password { get; set; }
strig ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

List<ViewModel.Participant> kids { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply filter your participants with

`var userParticipants = allParticipants.Where(p => p.UserId == Viewbag.UserId).ToList()`

It requires you to use the System.Linq namespace.

Edit:
Here's a more specific example

```
foreach(League i in Model)
            {
                var userParticipants = i.allParticipants.Where(p => p.UserId == Viewbag.UserId).ToList();
                foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in userParticipants)
                {
                    <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                }  
            }
```

Comment: could you give me an example? im not entirely sure how to do that. I'm fairly new to c# and mvc as a whole

Comment: i had to change `.Where(p => p.UserId` to `.Where(p => p.child.Parent.UserId`. other then that works as needed